# Illustrator: How to make 'lens elements', convex and concave, shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

Just starting out in Illustrator and I want to make a shape such as this:

[image]

**The way I have done it is like this:**

- Make a rectangle
- Move 2 corner anchor points

[image]

- Add anchor points on either side

[image]

- Move the recently added anchor points inward/outward

[image]

- Remove path (because I don't want some points curved) and `Effect->
  Stylise-> Rounded`

[image]

Now, when I go to remove the top anchor as a path, it removes the whole side.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have a look at http://shanfan.github.io/Illustrator-Scripts-Archive/. The 'round any corner' script has proved to be a lifesaver for me on many occasions as it's far better than what is built into illustrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Illustrator CS5, these lens-shaped objects can be created in a ridiculously simple and quick way by modifying a thick stroke using the `Width tool`. This also has the advantage of keeping the result editable.

1. Draw a path and give it an adequate stroke width (e.g. 10 pt), which will make for the base 'rectangle'.
2. Choose the `Width tool` (Shift+W) from the Tool palette, then click into the exact midpoint of the path and drag away from the centre (perpendicular direction). This curves both long sides, going from inwards to outwards, i.e., from **biconcave**  to **biconvex**.
   For a **plano-concave** or **plano-convex** shape (one straight side, one  curved side), keep the <kbd>Option</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed while dragging; it restricts the curving  to one side. This way, each side can be bulged independently, allowing for **concave-convex (meniscus)** shapes.
3. That's it. The curvatures can be changed at any time using the Width tool, and the initial stroke width (constituting the 'short sides') can be changed in the Appearance panel. However, to change the filling and give it an outer stroke, the object needs to be expanded (`Object > Expand Appearance`), which turns it from an Open Path object into a regular Closed Path object and diminishes easy editing. Expansion is also required if the shape is to be used in Pathfinder operations to construct a Compound Path/Shape object.

[image]

Comment: Can I change one side so it's more 'bowed' than the other?

Comment: Yes, the Width tool has some flexibility. See the Illustrator Help for details and video tutorials about the tool http://tv.adobe.com/watch/csinsider-design/illustrator-a-closer-look-at-the-variable-width-tool-for-illustration/

Answer (score 7):

There are quite some different lens elements, I will show you how to make a convex element.

### Convex

Make one ellipse, set it's line (stroke) color to black and the fill color to transparent:
[image]

Copy it and place the copy such that they overlay each other:
[image]

I've hatched the center part for illustrative purposes, in reality it will be white. The hatched part indicates the shape of your convex element. Change the size and placing of the ellipses such that the lens element shape has the desired thickness and length.

Select both ellipses, click `Window -> Pathfinder` and hit `Intersect`:
[image]

Your result should be:
[image]

### Concave

Again, start with one ellipse, copy it and place the copy such the ellipses don't overlap:
[image]

Draw a rectangle over the center part, like this:
[image]
Make sure that all corner points lie on the edge of an ellipse.

Your layers should be ordered like this:
[image]
If not, reorder the layers.

Now select the two ellipses and the rectangle, go to `Window -> Pathfinder` and click `Minus Back`:
[image]

You'll get something like this:
[image]

Again you can control the lens shape by placing and sizing the ellipses and the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry. Where is 'Intersect'?

Comment: In the pathfinder menu. The intersect button has a red square in [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lxfv0.png).

Comment: Hmm. I clicked on it and nothing happened. I'll have to play around more.

Comment: Make sure you've selected both ellipses. On another note: I think TehMacDawg's answer is better, so you should maybe try that (if you have CS5).